# MySQL: Combining two tables with null values does not print 0

Tags: mysql, join, datatable

In my code I am trying to combine two data tables, `Employee` and `Department`. I tried to write a query to print the respective Department Name and number of employees for all departments, even the unstaffed ones. My query looks like this:

```
SELECT department.name, count(department.name) AS CountOfNAME
FROM department LEFT JOIN employee ON department.dept_id = employee.dept_id
GROUP BY department.name
ORDER BY Count(department.name) DESC, department.name ASC;
```

And the result is:

```
Engineering 5
Recruitment 5
Sales 3
Product 2
Finance 1
Operations 1
Research&Development 1
```

This code works in that it orders departments by number of employees, and then alphabetically, but `Finance` and `Research&Development` are not supposed to have any people in them. Is there any way to correctly display those results as having 0 employees? It seems to be a hard thing to do in SQL because of how join works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `COUNT` function should ignore `NULL` values, giving you a zero count for the finance and research departments.  The problem is that you are counting a column in the `department` table, which always will be non `NULL` due to that this table is on the left side of the `LEFT JOIN`.  Instead, try counting a column in the `employee` table:

```
SELECT department.name,
       COUNT(employee.dept_id) AS CountOfNAME
FROM department
LEFT JOIN employee
    ON department.dept_id = employee.dept_id
GROUP BY department.name
ORDER BY COUNT(employee.dept_id) DESC,
         department.name ASC;
```

Comment: That worked well for making the 0s appear, but something odd is happening. The results now look like `Engineering 5 Recruitment 5 Sales 3 Product 2 Finance 0 Operations 1 Research&Development 0` , where the 1 is somehow between the 0s even though it is sorted by the count of the department name. Is there something in the code that is causing this anomaly? Sorry for not understand, I'm just learning SQL :)

Comment: Use `ORDER BY COUNT(employee.dept_id) DESC` ... sorry

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you create a view for the tallies of employees by department e.g.

```
  CREATE VIEW DepartmentEmployeeTallies
  AS
  SELECT dept_id, COUNT(*) AS tally
    FROM employee
  UNION
  SELECT dept_id, 0 AS tally
    FROM department
   WHERE dept_id NOT IN ( SELECT dept_id FROM employee );
```

Then things resolve to a simple join:

```
SELECT name, tally
  FROM department 
       NATURAL JOIN 
       DepartmentEmployeeTallies;
```